# Extra character added in batch script

Tags: windows-xp, batch-file

So, I think I may be going insane. This batch script:

```
@Echo on
dir > dir.txt
```

generates the following on the console it is run from:

```
dir  1>dir.txt
```

I expected to see simply dir > dir.txt. Any ideas why this is happening? This is on Windows XP SP2 in the standard command prompt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 1 is the [file descriptor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) for standard output. Therefore, these two commands are equivalent.

As a side note, you can redirect errors by redirecting descriptor 2, like this:

```
myCommand 1>goodoutput.txt 2>errors.txt
```

There's a nice summary of what you can do with redirection [here](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php).

Answer (score 0):

Your redirection operator (>) is essentially sending your command output to the stdout (standard output). "1" is the stdout handler.

You can also pipe to the stderr (error output); like in UNIX by using the "2" handler.

e.g 
myprogram.exe >> myoutput.txt 2>&1

For more information, see [Command Redirection](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true)